# border com cores alternadas (sem degrade)

Tags: css

Em uma borda de uma `div` `(border-bottom)` eu preciso aplicar mais de 1 cor porém sem utilizar o efeito de `degrade` que mescla as cores.

Imagem para exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com o efeito de degrade eu sei como fazer porém as cores se misturam, e se não forem `hexadecimais/rgb` proximos porém diferentes ficam estranhos.
Como posso fazer esse efeito de troca de cores sem mesclagem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Geralmente é feito com alguma coisa nessa linha de gradiente mesmo. É um gradiente, mas ele não mescla as cores pois as mudanças de cores são feitas de forma brusca, no mesmo ponto.

Se for exatamente disto que você está falando que quer evitar, creio que as únicas outras alternativas seriam **usando uma imagem** ou **criando diversas finas divs** alternadas.

De qualquer forma deixo dois exemplos, uma por gradiente e outra por finas divs.

### GRADIENTE

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background: #eee;
  height: 15px;
  width: 100vw;
}

.box:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #9400D3 14.3%, #4B0082 14.3%, #4B0082 28.6%, #0000FF 28.6%, #0000FF 42.9%, #00FF00 42.9%, #00FF00 57.2%, #FFFF00 57.2%, #FFFF00 71.5%, #FF7F00 71.5%, #FF7F00 85.8%, #FF0000 85.8%);
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 4px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

### DIVS

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;

}

#spacer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 11px;
  background: #eee;
}

#border {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
}

#border > div {
  width: 14.28%;
  height: 4px;
  float: left;
}

#border>div:nth-child(1) {
  background: #9400D3;
}

#border>div:nth-child(2) {
  background: #4B0082;
}

#border>div:nth-child(3) {
  background: #0000FF;
}

#border>div:nth-child(4) {
  background: #00FF00;
}

#border>div:nth-child(5) {
  background: #FFFF00;
}

#border>div:nth-child(6) {
  background: #FF7F00;
}

#border>div:nth-child(7) {
  background: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<div id="spacer"></div>
<div id="border">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```